# MacOS: .bash_profile is read as directory

Tags: bash

i have a question about bash on my MacOs. i have been instructed that to refresh env variables you just need to follow this command.

```
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

but i always get this error saying my `.bash_profile` is a directory.
i cannot provide you any details because it's not giving me any options as well.
Thanks.

Edit: this is the config of my `.bash_profile` 
`-rw-r--r--@ 1 {owner-name}  staff  3087 Sep  9 11:12 {path}`

Comment: Is the `~/.bash_profile` readable file? What is exact error message? Can you retry with absolute path?

Comment: this is the config for the bash_profile `-rw-r--r--@ `

Comment: Add output of `ls -ld ~/.bash_profile` to your question.

Comment: edited my question.

Comment: are you using bash shell? try `echo $SHELL`

Comment: What is exact error message?

Comment: eliminate a whole class of debugging problems by using fully qualified (and spelled out) paths to all files and programs, i.e. `/home/my_user_name/.bash_rc`, rather that `~/.bash_rc` or even `$HOME/.bash_rc`. Once you have identified and fix the source of your problem, you can return to using short cuts.

Comment: yes and the output of `echo $SHELL` is `/bin/bash`

Comment: What is the *exact* error? Are you sure the error message isn't coming from a command *inside* `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @chepner thanks for the hint. i got it working now. i notice one char `~` in my file and just deleted it. it works like a charm them :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all your help guys. chepner comment just help me solved my problem. i notice one special char in my file which is `~` and just deleted it and its working now. thanks you soo much really appreciate it.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I copy-pasted with the mouse from one Vim session to another, and I must have slurped up one of the `~` characters that Vim uses to represent editor lines past the end of the file. So it was camouflaged in my destination file! 

Answer (score 0):

It could be a folder... can you enter it? cd ~/.bash_profile

Comment: `Users/.bash_profile: Not a directory` that's the output. very strange.

Comment: And if you do?    cat  .bash_profile  is there text of?